# can not find the spring boot plugin in intellij idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm following a tutorial where the guy shows how to create a configuration using th "spring boot" support plugin but this pluugin is not available for me, neither in the list of templates nor in the Marketplace where i tried to add it, the tutorial is on a MAC and i'am on a windows is that the cause or there is something else ?

[image: run/debug configurations]

[image: Marketplace]

this is a screenshot from the tutorial :

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Plugins there is the Spring Boot Plugin ... when i deactivate it, spring boot template is missing.

Maybe you use the community edition? It doesnt support spring boot intellij features.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

You can use https://start.spring.io/ and download a gradle/maven project.

Comment: yes, i'm using the community edition, thank you for the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

**Intellij Community edition does not support Springboot projects. It is available only in Ultimate edition. This is the reason I switched back to Eclipse (or STS).**

There are few workarounds that will help you to run Springboot projects in Intellij Community edition:-

- By running Main class .
- By executing spring-boot:run command in terminal or cmd.
- You may need to change some settings to make spring-dev-tools work Intellij Community edition.

*My recommendation: If you are planning to use spring and spring-dev-tools then you should either switch to Intellij Ultimate edition or Eclipse STS.*

Reference:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows

Answer (score 1):

"spring boot" plugin is supported in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate version, not the Community version.

In Community version, there is another way to do this.

**Step 1:** Click "Add Configuration" on top right of the IDE. Then click "+" icon on the 'Run/Debug Configurations" window.
There you will see plugin as "Application". Click it

**Step 2:** Add the Main Class. Also add Environment variables and Program arguments if required.

(If need to add VM options as in Spring boot plugin in Idea Ultimate, follow step 3)

**Step 3:** Go to "modify options" on top right of the window(in blue lines). Then select "Add VM options" from the list. [Note: You can even select "include dependencies with 'Provided' scope". Helps in some projects.]

**Step 4:** Click 'Apply' and 'OK'. This will run the project as in Spring Boot plugin.

Comment: I am trying this solution. It will not allow me to select the main class.

Answer (score 0):

I did everything still didnt work ... But the solution was actually simple.
The problem was my JDK was 9 . So you can update your jdk to latest one and try, it will definitely work out. Use the latest intellij too.